# Select multi items all at once in Kendo UI Multi-Select?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

When use multi-select control in Kendo UI, it seems we have to select items one by one, i.e. click one item, the drop down list will collapse, then we have to click the multi-select control again to select the next item. Is it possible that when drop down list drops, user can select multiple items at the same time, so multiple items can add to the control at the same time, i.e. use CTRL + Mouse to select multiple items?

For example, in the below image, I want to select Nancy and Robert (i.e. use CTRL+MOUSE) and add them to list at the same time. Is it possible?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [autoClose](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect#configuration-autoClose) to false:

```
$("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
    autoClose: false
});
```